# Importing DWG/DXF to QGIS project

Tags: qgis

I am trying out importing a CAD DWG into an existing QGIS project but for some reason the "Source Drawing" option is looking for a geopackage extension while the "Target Package" is looking for a dwg/dxf extension.

When I browsed the net for a guide, videos around youtube shows me that the extension for "Source Drawing" should be in dwg.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This appears to be an issue with recent versions of QGIS. As of version 3.34.0-Prizren, it is still an issue.